# How to use PHP variable in a JQuery script

Tags: php, jquery

I found some similar questions but I couldnt figure out :(

This is my jQuery:

```
<script>
function avukat_change()
{
        if (jQuery("#AVUKATNO").val()=='14')
            jQuery("#fieldatamatarihi").show(1000);  
        else  
            jQuery("#fieldatamatarihi").hide(1000);
}
```

And I would like to replace '14' with this:

```
$UserID = scf_user_userid()
```

Comment: Is `scf_user_userid()` a PHP or JS function?

Comment: HTTP protocol + JSON.

Comment: where is `scf_user_userid()` defined? Can you run it in the same file or it is somewhere on the server-side.

Comment: You have three ways to do it: 1. Make webserver to pass .js files to PHP for parsing (not good idea). 2. Embed a small script in the .php file where you could define JS variables with values of PHP variables `var x = '<?php echo $x ?>';` and then call `func(x)` from JS file. 3. Make AJAX calls to request data from the server as @moonwave99 said (HTTP + JSON). I always bet on 3. where it is acceptable and use 2. for small tasks.

Comment: It defined in the same file. And problem is solved. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
function avukat_change()
{
    if (jQuery("#AVUKATNO").val()=='<? echo scf_user_userid();?>') 
       jQuery("#fieldatamatarihi").show(1000); 
    else  
       jQuery("#fieldatamatarihi").hide(1000);
}
```

Comment: Again you:) and again solved the problem. How many languages do you know? :)

Comment: @cvdogan programming languages or talking language? anyway 3-5

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function avukat_change()
{
    if (jQuery("#AVUKATNO").val() == '<?php echo scf_user_userid(); ?>') 
       jQuery("#fieldatamatarihi").show(1000); 
    else  
       jQuery("#fieldatamatarihi").hide(1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: missing ' ' around the php script like this: `'<?php ....?>'`

Comment: what if 14 was not a number but `'ab'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function avukat_change(){
    if (jQuery("#AVUKATNO").val()==<?php echo $UserID = scf_user_userid(); ?>)  jQuery("#fieldatamatarihi").show(1000); else  jQuery("#fieldatamatarihi").hide(1000);
}
```

Comment: Nope mate it didn't work :(

Comment: $UserID not needed in that line

Answer (score 0):

Or a quicker solution would be to do it shorthand.

```
<script>
function avukat_change()
{
    if (jQuery("#AVUKATNO").val()=='<?=scf_user_userid()?>') 
       jQuery("#fieldatamatarihi").show(1000); 
    else  
       jQuery("#fieldatamatarihi").hide(1000);
}
</script>
```